# Using of delete obsolete in Oracle 11gR2 RMAN on Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, delete, rman

I'm using crontab for automatic backup (full backup). It works 2 times in a day (8 AM and 23 PM). In my script I use delete obsolete but I have a question. I want to delete old backups without last 2 backup. Let's say:

Day 1: 8 AM

Day 1: 23 PM

Day 2: 8 AM (When my script run here and complete backup operation, after that my delete command should delete just Day 1: 8 AM backup)

How can I do it with delete obsolete command?

It's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/oracle/.bash_profile
RMANBACKUP_MOUNTPOINT1=/u01/backup/rman/
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=ORCL
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS"
rman target /  LOG '/oracle/backups/log/rman.log' << EOF
run{
allocate channel ch1 device type disk MAXPIECESIZE 200M;
allocate channel ch2 device type disk MAXPIECESIZE 200M;
backup spfile;
backup current controlfile;
backup database format '%d_%T_db' plus archivelog format '%d_%T_arch';
delete obsolete redundancy 2;
}
exit;
EOF
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are they full or incremental backups? It makes a difference

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ full backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell RMAN what you want/need to keep and let *it* do the worrying.

```
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 2 ;
```

That will keep *two* copies of your database and consider anything before that as obsolete.

I am a little concerned that you say you're only taking "full backups".

Are you backing up the ControlFiles?  The ArchiveLogs?
Without the former, you may have problems restoring a database after changing its structure (removing or even *adding* DataFiles) and without the latter, you lose any ability to perform a Point-in-Time Recovery.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your answer. Yes, it will backing up control files, spfile and also archivelogs. And can I use "delete obsolete redundancy 2;" ?

Comment: @neworacler: Keep things simple (for yourself).  Define the retention policies and just let RMAN apply them.  For example, with the retention policy configured, you just execute "delete obsolete".  RMAN will work out what it can and can't get rid of.  Also, to change your policy, you only have to reconfigure it in RMAN; all your scripts will adopt it.  If you code the retention policies into your scripts, you have to change all of them whenever you change the policy.